# regex and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have this PowerShell script, which shloud replace string inside quotas.

```
$filecontent = "[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(""Copyright © 2014-2015"")]"

$CopyrightRegex = "AssemblyCopyright(.+)"  
$toReplace = '"somethingToReplace"'                    
$result = $filecontent -replace $CopyrightRegex, "AssemblyCopyright($toReplace)" 
Write-Host $result
```

Result is

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("somethingToReplace")
```

But I'm excepting this: (last ] is missing)

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("somethingToReplace")]
```

Can you please point me, what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `AssemblyCopyright(.+)` your regex consumes the entire string, including the final `]`. It might be better to use the below:

```
$filecontent = '[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014-2015")]'
$toReplace = '"something"'
$result = $fileContent -replace "(.*AssemblyCopyright.*)\([^)]+\)(.*)","`$1($toReplace)`$2"
write-host $result
```

Though more complicated, it will grab everything before and after `("Copyright © 2014-2015")` and put them into capture groups. They can then be used in the replacement along with the new content `($toReplace)`

Comment: thank you, your script is working nicely. Can you please explain bit more why is my regex taking entire string? Thanks.

Comment: `.+` means match anything one or more times. Therefore it will match *everything* after `AssemblyCopyright` from the first open bracket `(` all the way to the end `]`